# Converting Windows cURL syntax to an equivalent InvokeRestMethod command

Tags: windows, powershell, curl

I am having trouble converting a working cURL command in Windows to an equivalent PowerShell InvokeRestMethod command.  It looks like I am pretty close.  I am getting a response.  However, the API doesn't seem to understand the nested hash table element **"domain"** sent by InvokeRestMethod command.  All other hash elements seem to be recognized by the API just fine.

**cURL command** *(working)*

```html
curl "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links" -X POST -H "apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"destination\": \"http://longurl.com\", \"domain\": {\"fullName\": \"link.domain.com\"}}"
```

**PowerShell:**

```PoSH
$body = @{
 "destination"="longurl.com"
 "domain" = @("fullName", "link.domain.com")
} | ConvertTo-Json

$header = @{
 "apikey"="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.rebrandly.com/v1/links" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header
```

PS:  I also tried using the below syntax.  Unfortunately, I get the same result.. where the "domain" hash element is ignored.

```PoSH
$body = @{
 "destination"="longurl.com"
 "domain[0]" = "fullName"
 "domain[1]" = "link.domain.com"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@(...)` brackets it is interpreted as an array and not as a key-value hashtable, which would be converted into an `[...]` array in JSON. Simply replace the brackets in the nested statement with the `@{...}` curly brackets to indicate a hashtable:

```
$body = @{
 "destination"="longurl.com"
 "domain" = @{"fullName" = "link.domain.com"}
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Which results in the matching JSON:

```
{
    "destination":  "longurl.com",
    "domain":  {
                   "fullName":  "link.domain.com"
               }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I had tried the brackets earlier.  However, I was still using a comma instead of an equal sign.